# Symbology of Outlines are Overlapping Instead of Layers

Tags: arcmap, symbology

I have three layers, three symbologies. If I create a group layer, the symbols are rendered differently than if I create a merged layer of all three layers.

Group layer:

[image]

Merged Layer:

[image]

Is there a way to get the merged layer symbology to look like the group layer symbology, where the symbol's outlines are layered, instead of combining. I understand that with merged layers, that the rules of layering may not apply, but I want to get rid of the noise from the outlines, while keeping them.

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1